# dynamic route appending throw error with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am getting following error when i try for dynamically loading the `route`

```
  return (
TS2739: Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'RouterProps': location, navigator
     8 |     <BrowserRouter>
  >  9 |       <Router>
       |        ^^^^^^
    10 |         {allModules.map((m: ModuleProps) => {
    11 |           return <Route path={m.routeProps.path} element={m.routeProps.element} key={m.name} />;
    12 |         })}
```

prop type:

```
export interface ModuleProps {
  name: string;
  routeProps: { path: string; element: React.ReactElement };
}
```

page:

```
import { FC } from 'react';

const Login: FC = () => {
  return <div>Login</div>;
};

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  routeProps: { path: '/login', element: <Login /> },
};
```

Module:

```
import LoginModule from './login';

export default [LoginModule];
```

App:

```
import { ModuleProps } from '@stonehenge-props/api-interfaces';
import { FC } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Router, RouterProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import allModules from './modules';

export const App: FC<RouterProps> = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Router>
        {allModules.map((m: ModuleProps) => {
          return <Route path={m.routeProps.path} element={m.routeProps.element} key={m.name} />;
        })}
      </Router>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index:

```
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './app/app';

const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The low-level `Router` component has a couple non-optional props that need to be passed, but you probably meant to import and render `Routes` instead of another `Router` component.

Also, since `App` isn't consuming any props there's no need to declare them in the function typing. Remove `RouterProps` from the declaration. Use either `const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {}` or just simply `const App = () => {}`.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import allModules from './modules';

export const App: FC<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {allModules.map((m: ModuleProps) => {
          return (
            <Route
              path={m.routeProps.path}
              element={m.routeProps.element}
              key={m.name}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit dynamic-route-appending-throw-error-with-typescript]

Comment: In index getting the error : `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'RouterProps': location, navigatorts`

Comment: @3gwebtrain Since `App` isn't consuming any props I don't think you need to specify them. Try `export const App = () => { .....`.

Comment: No, still the issue is not solved

Comment: @3gwebtrain What or where exactly is that error from then? I can't reproduce it in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-route-appending-throw-error-with-typescript-flidcl?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: please check you `index.ts` file. lint throws the error, since strict mode

Comment: @3gwebtrain I see. Yeah, like I said, use either `App = () => {}` or remove the `RouterProps` props type since they aren't used, i.e. `App: FC<{}> = () => {}`.

Comment: `App = () => {}` - works. thanks!!